# nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Column 'createdBy' not found

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

```
String sql = "select *,T.createdBy_id,(select count(*) from subscription S where S.topic_id=T.id) as subscriptionCount,"+
            "(select count(*) from resource R where R.topic_id=T.id) as topicCount from topic T "+
            "WHERE T.createdBy_id=6";
```

If I execute same query on mySQL shell, it works fine.
I have been trying this since a long time.Help appreciated

Comment: Is that subquery in the `where` clause really necessary? Seems to be you could simply write `WHERE T.createdBy_id = 6`?

Comment: That deoesnt works either. @waka